# How to create html table dynamically using loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

I want to display result in html table of array data using php `foreach` or `for` loop. I have placed array below. In the array there is field 'bs_column' and it values can be 12, 6 or 4. In the loop I want to display one `td` in each `tr`(one column in each row) if bs_column is equal 12 and two `td` in each `tr`(two column in each row) if bs_column==6 and three `td` in each `tr` (three column in each row) if bs_column==4.
In case if not paired bs_column==6 which are two fields (`<tr><td>field one</td><td>field two</td></tr>`) in loop sequence then need to one column in a row (`<tr><td>single field</td></tr>`).
In case if not paired bs_column==4 which are three fields (`<tr><td>field one</td><td>field two</td><td>field three</td></tr>`) in loop sequence then make two fields (`<tr><td>field one</td><td>field two</td></tr>`) pair if not pair then make single field (`<tr><td>single field</td></tr>`) in column in row.

Array is

```
$fields= Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [form_id] => 3 [name] => THE APPLICANT [slug] => customers_the-applicant_heading [required] => 0 [type] => heading [options] => [field_order] => 0 [bs_column] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Applicant(s) Name [slug] => customers_applicants-name_input [required] => 0 [type] => input [options] => [field_order] => 1 [bs_column] => 12 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Email [slug] => customers_email_input [required] => 0 [type] => input [options] => [field_order] => 2 [bs_column] => 6 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Telephone [slug] => customers_telephone_input [required] => 0 [type] => input [options] => [field_order] => 3 [bs_column] => 6 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 5 [form_id] => 3 [name] => s this Property currently insured? [slug] => customers_s-this-property-currently-insured_checkbox [required] => 0 [type] => select [options] => Yes,No [field_order] => 4 [bs_column] => 12 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 6 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Name of insurer(s) [slug] => customers_name-of-insurers_input [required] => 0 [type] => input [options] => [field_order] => 5 [bs_column] => 6 ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 7 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Current insurer expiry date [slug] => customers_current-insurer-expiry-date_date_picker [required] => 0 [type] => date_picker [options] => [field_order] => 6 [bs_column] => 6 ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 8 [form_id] => 3 [name] => D.O.B. of eldest insured [slug] => customers_dob-of-eldest-insured_date_picker [required] => 0 [type] => date_picker [options] => [field_order] => 7 [bs_column] => 6 ) [8] => Array ( [id] => 9 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Applicant postal address [slug] => customers_applicant-postal-address_input [required] => 0 [type] => textarea [options] => [field_order] => 8 [bs_column] => 12 ) [9] => Array ( [id] => 10 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Suburb [slug] => customers_suburb_input [required] => 0 [type] => input [options] => [field_order] => 9 [bs_column] => 4 ) [10] => Array ( [id] => 11 [form_id] => 3 [name] => State [slug] => customers_state_input [required] => 0 [type] => input [options] => [field_order] => 10 [bs_column] => 4 ) [11] => Array ( [id] => 12 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Postcode [slug] => customers_postcode_input [required] => 0 [type] => input [options] => [field_order] => 11 [bs_column] => 4 ) [12] => Array ( [id] => 13 [form_id] => 3 [name] => PERIOD OF INSURANCE [slug] => customers_period-of-insurance_heading [required] => 0 [type] => heading [options] => [field_order] => 12 [bs_column] => 12 ) [13] => Array ( [id] => 14 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Cover required From [slug] => customers_cover-required-from_input [required] => 0 [type] => input [options] => [field_order] => 13 [bs_column] => 6 ) [14] => Array ( [id] => 15 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Cover required to [slug] => customers_cover-required-to_input [required] => 0 [type] => input [options] => [field_order] => 14 [bs_column] => 6 ) [15] => Array ( [id] => 16 [form_id] => 3 [name] => INSURED DETAILS [slug] => customers_insured-details_heading [required] => 0 [type] => heading [options] => [field_order] => 15 [bs_column] => 12 ) [16] => Array ( [id] => 17 [form_id] => 3 [name] => What are the premises you wish to insure? [slug] => customers_what-are-the-premises-you-wish-to-insure-_note [required] => 0 [type] => note [options] => [field_order] => 16 [bs_column] => 12 ) [17] => Array ( [id] => 18 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Address of property [slug] => customers_address-of-property_input [required] => 0 [type] => input [options] => [field_order] => 17 [bs_column] => 12 ) [18] => Array ( [id] => 19 [form_id] => 3 [name] => CONSTRUCTION DETAILS [slug] => customers_construction-details_heading [required] => 0 [type] => heading [options] => [field_order] => 21 [bs_column] => 12 ) [19] => Array ( [id] => 20 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Cover type required [slug] => customers_cover-type-required_checkbox [required] => 0 [type] => checkbox [options] => Specified events,Accidental damage (specified events + accidental damage) [field_order] => 22 [bs_column] => 12 ) [20] => Array ( [id] => 23 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Year built [slug] => customers_year-built_date_picker [required] => 0 [type] => date_picker [options] => [field_order] => 25 [bs_column] => 6 ) [21] => Array ( [id] => 24 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Number of storeys [slug] => customers_number-of-storeys_input [required] => 0 [type] => input [options] => [field_order] => 26 [bs_column] => 6 ) [22] => Array ( [id] => 25 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Is the building elevated or multi storey? [slug] => customers_is-the-building-elevated-or-multi-storey_checkbox [required] => 0 [type] => checkbox [options] => Single storey,Single storey elevated,Double storey,Three or more storey [field_order] => 27 [bs_column] => 12 ) [23] => Array ( [id] => 26 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Is the property well maintained structurally sound and secured against wind and rain? [slug] => customers_is-the-property-well-maintained-structurally-sound-and-secured-against-wind-and-rain_checkbox [required] => 0 [type] => checkbox [options] => Yes,No [field_order] => 28 [bs_column] => 12 ) [24] => Array ( [id] => 27 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Is the property undergoing renovations over $75,000, OR, under construction, OR, to be demolished? [slug] => customers_is-the-property-undergoing-renovations-over-75000-or-under-construction-or-to-be-demolished_checkbox [required] => 0 [type] => checkbox [options] => Yes,No [field_order] => 29 [bs_column] => 12 ) [25] => Array ( [id] => 28 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Is your home location on a site exceeding 20,000 square metres? [slug] => customers_is-your-home-location-on-a-site-exceeding-20000-square-metres_checkbox [required] => 0 [type] => checkbox [options] => Yes,No [field_order] => 30 [bs_column] => 12 ) [26] => Array ( [id] => 29 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Has the land where the building or contents are been flooded or inundated by water more than once in the last 10 years? [slug] => customers_has-the-land-where-the-building-or-contents-are-been-flooded-or-inundated-by-water-more-than-once-in-the-last-10-years_checkbox [required] => 0 [type] => checkbox [options] => Yes,No [field_order] => 31 [bs_column] => 12 ) [27] => Array ( [id] => 30 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Is there a pool on your property? [slug] => customers_is-there-a-pool-on-your-property_checkbox [required] => 0 [type] => checkbox [options] => Yes,No [field_order] => 32 [bs_column] => 6 ) [28] => Array ( [id] => 31 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Building type: [slug] => customers_building-type_checkbox [required] => 0 [type] => checkbox [options] => House on slab/foundation,House on poles,Villa/Townhouse,Unit/Flat,Terrace/semi,Course of construction,Granny flat,Heritage property,Holiday home,Mobile home,Display home,Nursing home Caravan,Retirement village [field_order] => 33 [bs_column] => 12 ) [29] => Array ( [id] => 32 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Floor Construction: [slug] => customers_floor-construction_checkbox [required] => 0 [type] => checkbox [options] => Concrete,Wood [field_order] => 31 [bs_column] => 6 ) [30] => Array ( [id] => 34 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Wall construction:If mixed construction, please detail % of each [slug] => customers_wall-constructionif-mixed-construction-please-detail-of-each_checkbox [required] => 0 [type] => checkbox [options] => Double Brick Timber/,Brick Veneer Steel,Weatherboard,Fibro/Asbestos,Concrete/Hebel,Stone/ Sandstone,Cement,Polystyrene/EP,Mud brick [field_order] => 33 [bs_column] => 12 ) [31] => Array ( [id] => 35 [form_id] => 3 [name] => other [slug] => customers_other_input [required] => 0 [type] => input [options] => [field_order] => 34 [bs_column] => 12 ) [32] => Array ( [id] => 36 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Roof: [slug] => customers_roof_checkbox [required] => 0 [type] => checkbox [options] => Cement Tiles,Iron,Slate,Terracotta,Colour bond,Steel,Wood [field_order] => 35 [bs_column] => 12 ) [33] => Array ( [id] => 37 [form_id] => 3 [name] => other [slug] => customers_other_input [required] => 0 [type] => input [options] => [field_order] => 36 [bs_column] => 12 ) [34] => Array ( [id] => 38 [form_id] => 3 [name] => Sandwich Foam Panel construction (EPS) [slug] => customers_sandwich-foam-panel-construction-eps_checkbox [required] => 0 [type] => checkbox [options] => Yes,No [field_order] => 37 [bs_column] => 6 ) [35] => Array ( [id] => 39 [form_id] => 3 [name] => If yes, percentage % [slug] => customers_if-yes-percentage-_input [required] => 0 [type] => input [options] => [field_order] => 38 [bs_column] => 6 ) )`
```

php code

```
 $max_six_per_row = 2;
   $max_four_per_row = 3;
   $item_count_two = 0;
   $item_count_three = 0;
 $fields_html .= '<table><tbody>';
foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $field['name'] = $field['name'];
        if ($field['bs_column'] == 12) {
             $fields_html .="<tr><td width='100%'>".$field['name'] ."</td></tr>";   
            } 
        if ($field['bs_column'] == 6) {
        if ($item_count_two == 0)
        {
            $fields_html .="<tr>";
        }
             $fields_html .="<td width='50%'>".$field['name'] ."</td>";
        if ($item_count_two == $max_six_per_row)
        {
            $fields_html .="</tr>";
            $item_count_two = 0;
        }
            $item_count_two++;
         } 
        if ($field['bs_column'] == 4) {
        if ($item_count_three == 0)
        {
            $fields_html .="<tr>";
        }
             $fields_html .="<td>".$field['name'] ."</td>";
        if ($item_count_three == $max_four_per_row)
        {
            $fields_html .="</tr>";
            $item_count_three = 0;
        }
            $item_count_three++;
       }
      
      }
      $fields_html .= '</tbody></table>';
     echo $fields_html;
```

Comment: If you plan on haveing a maximum of 3 td's then all your rows should have 3 td's.  You need to use COLSPAN to join all 3 td's into 1 or 2 when needed.

Comment: Problem is opening `<tr>` and closing `</tr>`.  in above loop when `bs_column==6` has two rows it open `<tr>`  one time and close `</tr>`  two time.

Comment: Your logic escapes me.  I understood that you want to print either 1, 2 or 3 td's per row.  Am I mistaken?  In the bs_column==6 section you test $item_count_two == 0, which is true, so you insert a tr.  Then you add 1 td cell. Then you test $item_count_two == $max_six_per_row.  Since you never increment $item_count_two I don't see how that test will pass because $item_count_two will never equal 2.  Let me mull it over.  I'll post an answer after that.

Comment: Well I ran into a problem.  Your $fields array is invalid.  PHP is case sensitive so the array command is lowercase.  I took the 1st entry and converted it to this: '$fields = array(0 => array("id" => 1, "form_id" => 3, "name" => "THE APPLICANT", "slug" => "customers_the-applicant_heading", "required" => 0, "type" => "heading", "options" => array("field_order" => 0, "bs_column" => 12)));'.  Does this look correct?  I got to start with a valid array.

Comment: Yes it is valid array . It will be helpful if you will post an answer with suggestion or with correction of above mentioned loop. Thanks @CharlesEF

Comment: Yes I need same logic 1 2 and 3 `tds` per row but when not paired 2 `tds` then one `td` per row and also three if not paired three then two or one `td` per row

Comment: So are you saying my sample array is correct?  Before I can write code the array has to be correct.

Comment: Sorry the array '$fields = array(0 => array("id" => 1, "form_id" => 3, "name" => "THE APPLICANT", "slug" => "customers_the-applicant_heading", "required" => 0, "type" => "heading", "options" => array("field_order" => 0, "bs_column" => 12)));'. is not correct. Copy and paste the whole array into editor and replace `Array` with `array`.

Comment: I did that, still not valid.  Array is not the only problem. A lot of the keys have [] around them but they're not arrays.  Let me try again.

Comment: Thanks try if it will correct. go to this link and copy the json array and decode in php it will correct output [https://onlinegsali.com/phparray/

Comment: Ok, I changed Array to array and it still is invalid.  You don't have commas separating key/value pairs.  You don't have quotes around strings.  Numbers don't need quotes but strings do.  It would be better if you fixed the array.  Just follow my sample array.  As a test do a foreach($fields as $row).  Inside the foreach do print_r($row).  Then view source and check the array.  Once you fix the array post it in your question.  Then I can write code.

Comment: Thanks try if it will correct. go to this link and copy the json array and decode in php it will correct output [https://onlinegsali.com/phparray/

Comment: I went to the URL and copied and pasted the array. I placed it in a foreach loop with the print_r() command and I get this error: 'syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']''.  If I try to use json_decode then I get this error: 'syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']''.  So I get the same error either way.  Can you test the foreach loop I suggested?  What happens for you?

Comment: And yes I did copy the entire contents of the URL.  In fact I did it twice and I still get the syntax error.

Comment: Copy the entire content from provided url and paste like this `$arr='[{"id":"21","name":"THE APPLICANT","req":"0","type":"heading","opt":"","f_ord":"0","b_c":"12","val":""},{"id":"22","name":".....}]'` afte pasting go down and decode the `$arr` like this `$de_arr=json_decode($arr,true);` then print the `print_r($de_arr)` it will show the correct result and you can use in foreach loop.

Comment: Well the problem was my double quotes.  I wrapped your array in double quotes and used json_decode() on it and got the errors I reported.  In your example I saw you used single quotes so I tried that, and it worked.  I'm going to need some time to come up with code but it's 2:30AM here so check back later.

Comment: I see the key names don't match what you posted.  In your post you use 'bs_column' but in the array it is 'b_c'.  Correct?

Comment: I need better understanding.  b_c = 12 then 1 td, b_c = 6 then 2 td's, b_c = 4 then 3 td's.  When 1 td you use '$field['name']'.  When 2 or 3 td's do you still want to use '$field['name']' as the 1st td and td 2 will use the same field but from the next row?  3 td's follows the same logic, 1st field is from current row and the 2nd td is from the next row and the 3rd td is from the row after that.  Is my understanding correct?  When you talk about pairs how do you know that is something is paired?

Comment: Thank You for your struggle. You can print anything `'$field['name'] or else`. Main thing is displaying tds in tr. Same as  b_c = 12 then 1 td, b_c = 6 then 2 td's, b_c = 4 then 3 td's.

Comment: Are the fields from another row?  Or, do you want the same field showing 2 or 3 times from the same row?  This is important so I get the logic right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is a 1st draft.  I need a better understanding of field2 and field3.  Do they come from the same field name from different rows?  Or is field from the same row?  Depending on your answer this code logic might change.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Loop Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$rows = json_decode('[{"id":"21","name":"THE APPLICANT","req":"0","type":"heading","opt":"","f_ord":"0","b_c":"12","val":""},{"id":"22","name":"Applicant(s) Name","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"1","b_c":"12","val":"Ali Hasan"},{"id":"23","name":"Email","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"2","b_c":"6","val":"ghulamseratalikhan@gmail.com"},{"id":"24","name":"Telephone","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"3","b_c":"6","val":"03100865443"},{"id":"25","name":"s this Property currently insured?","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Yes,No","f_ord":"4","b_c":"12","val":"No"},{"id":"26","name":"Name of insurer(s)","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"5","b_c":"6","val":"Insurer Name"},{"id":"27","name":"Current insurer expiry date","req":"0","type":"date_picker","opt":"","f_ord":"6","b_c":"6","val":"2021-08-20 00:00:00"},{"id":"28","name":"D.O.B. of eldest insured","req":"0","type":"date_picker","opt":"","f_ord":"7","b_c":"6","val":"2006-08-24 00:00:00"},{"id":"29","name":"Applicant postal address","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"8","b_c":"12","val":"1535 service road g-11\/2 Islamabad first floor"},{"id":"30","name":"Suburb","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"9","b_c":"12","val":"Capital Terriority"},{"id":"31","name":"State","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"10","b_c":"6","val":"Capital"},{"id":"32","name":"Postcode","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"11","b_c":"6","val":"58000"},{"id":"33","name":"PERIOD OF INSURANCE","req":"0","type":"heading","opt":"","f_ord":"12","b_c":"12","val":""},{"id":"34","name":"Cover required From","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"13","b_c":"6","val":"Rashid Ali"},{"id":"35","name":"Cover required to","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"14","b_c":"6","val":"Hasan Ali"},{"id":"36","name":"INSURED DETAILS","req":"0","type":"heading","opt":"","f_ord":"15","b_c":"12","val":""},{"id":"37","name":"What are the premises you wish to insure? ","req":"0","type":"note","opt":"","f_ord":"16","b_c":"12","val":""},{"id":"38","name":"Address of property","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"17","b_c":"12","val":"F-10\/4 house 45 street 345 near F-10 marakaz"},{"id":"39","name":"CONSTRUCTION DETAILS","req":"0","type":"heading","opt":"","f_ord":"21","b_c":"12","val":""},{"id":"40","name":"Cover type required","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Specified events","f_ord":"22","b_c":"4","val":""},{"id":"41","name":"OR ","req":"0","type":"note","opt":"","f_ord":"23","b_c":"4","val":""},{"id":"42","name":"","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Accidental damage (specified events + accidental damage)","f_ord":"24","b_c":"4","val":"Accidental damage (specified events + accidental damage)"},{"id":"43","name":"Year built","req":"0","type":"date_picker","opt":"","f_ord":"25","b_c":"6","val":"2014-08-22 00:00:00"},{"id":"44","name":"Number of storeys","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"26","b_c":"6","val":"3"},{"id":"45","name":"Is the building elevated or multi storey?","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Single storey,Single storey elevated,Double storey,Three or more storey","f_ord":"27","b_c":"12","val":"Double storey, Three or more storey"},{"id":"46","name":"Is the property well maintained structurally sound and secured against wind and rain?","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Yes,No","f_ord":"28","b_c":"12","val":"Yes"},{"id":"47","name":"Is the property undergoing renovations over $75,000, OR, under construction, OR, to be demolished?","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Yes,No","f_ord":"29","b_c":"12","val":"Yes"},{"id":"48","name":"Is your home location on a site exceeding 20,000 square metres?","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Yes,No","f_ord":"30","b_c":"12","val":"No"},{"id":"49","name":"Has the land where the building or contents are been flooded or inundated by water more than once in the last 10 years?","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Yes,No","f_ord":"31","b_c":"12","val":"Yes"},{"id":"50","name":"Is there a pool on your property?","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Yes,No","f_ord":"32","b_c":"12","val":"Yes"},{"id":"51","name":"Building type:","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"House on slab\/foundation,House on poles,Villa\/Townhouse,Unit\/Flat,Terrace\/semi,Course of construction,Granny flat,Heritage property,Holiday home,Mobile home,Display home,Nursing home Caravan,Retirement village","f_ord":"33","b_c":"12","val":"House on poles, Unit\/Flat, Holiday home, Mobile home, Display home"},{"id":"52","name":"Floor Construction:","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Concrete,Wood","f_ord":"31","b_c":"6","val":"Concrete, Wood"},{"id":"53","name":"Other","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"32","b_c":"6","val":"Marble Sfloor"},{"id":"54","name":"Wall construction:If mixed construction, please detail % of each<\/small>","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Double Brick Timber\/,Brick Veneer Steel,Weatherboard,Fibro\/Asbestos,Concrete\/Hebel,Stone\/ Sandstone,Cement,Polystyrene\/EP,Mud brick","f_ord":"33","b_c":"12","val":"Weatherboard, Fibro\/Asbestos, Cement, Mud brick"},{"id":"55","name":"other","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"34","b_c":"12","val":"Mud bv construction"},{"id":"56","name":"Roof:","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Cement Tiles,Iron,Slate,Terracotta,Colour bond,Steel,Wood","f_ord":"35","b_c":"12","val":"Cement Tiles, Slate, Colour bond"},{"id":"57","name":"other","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"36","b_c":"12","val":"steael wooddd roof"},{"id":"58","name":"Sandwich Foam Panel construction (EPS)","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Yes,No","f_ord":"37","b_c":"4","val":"Yes"},{"id":"59","name":"If yes, percentage %","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"38","b_c":"4","val":"45%"}]', true);
//$max_cols = 3;
//$max_tds = 1;
echo("<table>" . PHP_EOL);
echo(" <tbody>" . PHP_EOL);
foreach($rows as $key => $row)
{
 echo("  <tr>" . PHP_EOL);
 switch($row["b_c"])
 {
  case 4:
   echo("   <td>{$row['name']}</td><td>{$row['name']}</td><td>{$row['name']}</td>" . PHP_EOL);
//   $max_tds = 3;
   break;
  case 6:
   echo("   <td>{$row['name']}</td><td>{$row['name']}</td><td></td>" . PHP_EOL);
//   $max_tds = 2;
   break;
  case 12:
   echo("   <td>{$row['name']}</td><td></td><td></td>" . PHP_EOL);
//   $max_tds = 1;
   break;
  default:
   echo("   <td>{$row['name']}</td><td></td><td></td>" . PHP_EOL);
   break;
 }
 echo("  </tr>" . PHP_EOL);
// echo("Key: " . $key . PHP_EOL);
// print_r($row);
}
echo(" </tbody>" . PHP_EOL);
echo("</table>" . PHP_EOL);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Once I have a better understanding I can help change this code.

Comment: It duplicate the records in display. However thanks for providing solution. I will post the solution here which is correct and display records accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Table displayed correct output. In `foreach` loop first need to check `$field['b_c']==6`
,the this check if two tds paired inside a tr then close the tr and if not paired and source data has single consecutive `$field['b_c']==6` row then also close tr. 2nd need to check if `$field['b_c']==4` and close tr if rows less than three or equal to three.
For `$field['b_c']==12` just one row and one column.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Loop Test</title>
 <style>
.table{
    /*width:100%;*/
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin:30px;
    padding:8px;
}
.table tr,.table tr>td{
     border:1px solid #ccc;
     padding:5px;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$rows = json_decode('[{"id":"21","name":"THE APPLICANT","req":"0","type":"heading","opt":"","f_ord":"0","b_c":"12","val":""},{"id":"22","name":"Applicant(s) Name","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"1","b_c":"12","val":"Ali Hasan"},{"id":"23","name":"Email","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"2","b_c":"6","val":"ghulamseratalikhan@gmail.com"},{"id":"24","name":"Telephone","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"3","b_c":"6","val":"03100865443"},{"id":"25","name":"s this Property currently insured?","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Yes,No","f_ord":"4","b_c":"12","val":"No"},{"id":"26","name":"Name of insurer(s)","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"5","b_c":"6","val":"Insurer Name"},{"id":"27","name":"Current insurer expiry date","req":"0","type":"date_picker","opt":"","f_ord":"6","b_c":"6","val":"2021-08-20 00:00:00"},{"id":"28","name":"D.O.B. of eldest insured","req":"0","type":"date_picker","opt":"","f_ord":"7","b_c":"6","val":"2006-08-24 00:00:00"},{"id":"29","name":"Applicant postal address","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"8","b_c":"12","val":"1535 service road g-11\/2 Islamabad first floor"},{"id":"30","name":"Suburb","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"9","b_c":"12","val":"Capital Terriority"},{"id":"31","name":"State","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"10","b_c":"6","val":"Capital"},{"id":"32","name":"Postcode","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"11","b_c":"6","val":"58000"},{"id":"33","name":"PERIOD OF INSURANCE","req":"0","type":"heading","opt":"","f_ord":"12","b_c":"12","val":""},{"id":"34","name":"Cover required From","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"13","b_c":"6","val":"Rashid Ali"},{"id":"35","name":"Cover required to","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"14","b_c":"6","val":"Hasan Ali"},{"id":"36","name":"INSURED DETAILS","req":"0","type":"heading","opt":"","f_ord":"15","b_c":"12","val":""},{"id":"37","name":"What are the premises you wish to insure? ","req":"0","type":"note","opt":"","f_ord":"16","b_c":"12","val":""},{"id":"38","name":"Address of property","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"17","b_c":"12","val":"F-10\/4 house 45 street 345 near F-10 marakaz"},{"id":"39","name":"CONSTRUCTION DETAILS","req":"0","type":"heading","opt":"","f_ord":"21","b_c":"12","val":""},{"id":"40","name":"Cover type required","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Specified events","f_ord":"22","b_c":"4","val":""},{"id":"41","name":"OR ","req":"0","type":"note","opt":"","f_ord":"23","b_c":"4","val":""},{"id":"42","name":"","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Accidental damage (specified events + accidental damage)","f_ord":"24","b_c":"4","val":"Accidental damage (specified events + accidental damage)"},{"id":"43","name":"Year built","req":"0","type":"date_picker","opt":"","f_ord":"25","b_c":"6","val":"2014-08-22 00:00:00"},{"id":"44","name":"Number of storeys","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"26","b_c":"6","val":"3"},{"id":"45","name":"Is the building elevated or multi storey?","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Single storey,Single storey elevated,Double storey,Three or more storey","f_ord":"27","b_c":"12","val":"Double storey, Three or more storey"},{"id":"46","name":"Is the property well maintained structurally sound and secured against wind and rain?","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Yes,No","f_ord":"28","b_c":"12","val":"Yes"},{"id":"47","name":"Is the property undergoing renovations over $75,000, OR, under construction, OR, to be demolished?","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Yes,No","f_ord":"29","b_c":"12","val":"Yes"},{"id":"48","name":"Is your home location on a site exceeding 20,000 square metres?","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Yes,No","f_ord":"30","b_c":"12","val":"No"},{"id":"49","name":"Has the land where the building or contents are been flooded or inundated by water more than once in the last 10 years?","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Yes,No","f_ord":"31","b_c":"12","val":"Yes"},{"id":"50","name":"Is there a pool on your property?","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Yes,No","f_ord":"32","b_c":"12","val":"Yes"},{"id":"51","name":"Building type:","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"House on slab\/foundation,House on poles,Villa\/Townhouse,Unit\/Flat,Terrace\/semi,Course of construction,Granny flat,Heritage property,Holiday home,Mobile home,Display home,Nursing home Caravan,Retirement village","f_ord":"33","b_c":"12","val":"House on poles, Unit\/Flat, Holiday home, Mobile home, Display home"},{"id":"52","name":"Floor Construction:","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Concrete,Wood","f_ord":"31","b_c":"6","val":"Concrete, Wood"},{"id":"53","name":"Other","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"32","b_c":"6","val":"Marble Sfloor"},{"id":"54","name":"Wall construction:If mixed construction, please detail % of each<\/small>","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Double Brick Timber\/,Brick Veneer Steel,Weatherboard,Fibro\/Asbestos,Concrete\/Hebel,Stone\/ Sandstone,Cement,Polystyrene\/EP,Mud brick","f_ord":"33","b_c":"12","val":"Weatherboard, Fibro\/Asbestos, Cement, Mud brick"},{"id":"55","name":"other","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"34","b_c":"12","val":"Mud bv construction"},{"id":"56","name":"Roof:","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Cement Tiles,Iron,Slate,Terracotta,Colour bond,Steel,Wood","f_ord":"35","b_c":"12","val":"Cement Tiles, Slate, Colour bond"},{"id":"57","name":"other","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"36","b_c":"12","val":"steael wooddd roof"},{"id":"58","name":"Sandwich Foam Panel construction (EPS)","req":"0","type":"checkbox","opt":"Yes,No","f_ord":"37","b_c":"4","val":"Yes"},{"id":"59","name":"If yes, percentage %","req":"0","type":"input","opt":"","f_ord":"38","b_c":"4","val":"45%"}]', true);
//count tds inside a rows when 'b_c'=6 or 'b_c'=4. 
    $tempSixCount = 0;
    $tempfourCount = 0;
    $table='<table class="table"><tbody>';
foreach ($rows as $k=>$field) {
            $field_name = $field['name'];
            $value = $field['val'];
            if ($field['b_c'] == '' || $field['b_c'] == 0) {
                $field['b_c'] = 12;
            }
    //first check if b_c=6
    if($field['b_c'] == 6){
        //opening tr @row start here for b_c=6
            if($tempSixCount==0){
               $table .='<tr>';
            }
$table .='<td colspan="2"><strong>'.$field_name.':</strong> '.$value.'</td>'; 
//increasing tds inside tr for b_c=6
           $tempSixCount++;
//second check if b_c=4
        }elseif($field['b_c'] == 4){
    //opening tr @row start here for b_c=4
            if($tempfourCount==0){
               $table .='<tr>';
            }
$table .='<td colspan=""><strong>'.$field_name.':</strong> '.$value.'</td>';
//increasing tds inside tr for b_c=4
           $tempfourCount++;
//on else condition it will check b_c=12 and also close tr for above b_c=6 and b_c=4 
      }else{
//here check if for b_c=6 has not pair of two tds inside a tr and has single td then clsoe tr and start again counting tds from 0.  
                    if($tempSixCount>0)
                    {
                        $table .='</tr>';
                        $tempSixCount = 0;
                    }
//here check if for b_c=4 has not pair of three tds inside a tr and has single td or two tds then clsoe tr and start again counting tds from 0.  
                    if($tempfourCount>0)
                    {
                        $table .='</tr>';
                        $tempfourCount = 0;
                    }
// open and clsoe tr having single tds bcoz b_c=12 has one row and one column 
                    if($field['b_c'] == 12)
                    {
$table .='<tr><td colspan="3"><strong>'.$field_name.':</strong> '.$value.'</td></tr>';
                    } 
            }
//here check if for b_c=6 has pair of two tds inside a tr then clsoe tr and start again counting tds from 0.
                if ($tempSixCount == 2)
                {
                    $table .='</tr>';
                    $tempSixCount = 0;
                }
//here check if for b_c=4 has pair of three tds inside a tr then clsoe tr and start again counting tds from 0.
                if ($tempfourCount == 3)
                {
                    $table .='</tr>';
                    $tempfourCount = 0;
                }
}
 $table .='</tbody></table>';
 echo $table;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.  I still don't understand what is 'paired' or I would have included that in my code.  Anyway, glad it worked out for you.

Comment: I appreciated your work. I learn from your provided code it will be good if I use switch. Paired mean, for example pair of two tds inside a tr `<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>` and will create dynamically these tds from data rows (may it consecutive or discrete) for `$row['b_c']==6`. same for `$row['b_c']==4` but here pair of 3 tds inside a tr.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now.  But if b_c is 4, 6 or 12 my code then it doesn't care about pairs.  I can see where you might want to write a single td at a time but I can't see why.  Unless you go to the next data row to get a different field value.  Anyway, glad I could help.